# Can only one element of an array make a subarray?

Tags: c, arrays

I am not clear about subarray.

suppose: `A[3]={1,2,3}`

Can 1,2 and 3 individually be subarrays of A?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "sub-arrays"? And in what language?

Comment: theoretically yes, but practically it depends on what programming language are you using.

Comment: I think it depends on the object type. But yes, you could do this.

Comment: Can you tell us which language you are using, e.g. by tagging your question with the language name?

Comment: I am using C proramming language. Can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. In C, array is basically a pointer alongside with its length.

You could do this:

```
int A[3] = {1,2,3};
int * p1 = A;   // or p1 = &A[0]
int * p2 = A+2; // or p2 = &A[2];
```

And now you can operate on `p1` as an array of 2 elements (`{1,2}`), and `p2` as an array of 1 element (`{3}`), but you have to know or remember this information about sub-array lengths yourself.